# Select from one table what doesn't exist three times in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have one table full of different projects students have submitted.  Each project should be judged by three different judges.  So there's another table of scores that includes projectid and judgeid.  I'm trying to write a query that can select any project that hasn't been judged three times yet.

Here's some sample tables...

**Projects**

```
projectid | projectname
-----------------------
9         | Kintetics
11        | Volcano
15        | Robots
22        | Oceanlife
```

**Scores**

```
scoreid (AI) | projectid | judgeid | score
------------------------------------------
1            | 9         | 15      | 5
2            | 11        | 15      | 18
3            | 9         | 23      | 12
4            | 11        | 23      | 11
5            | 9         | 45      | 19
6            | 22        | 15      | 3
```

I would expect this query to return projects 11, 15, and 22 because those three don't have three judges assigned to them yet.

Comment: Will you rephrase your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ProjectID, a.ProjectName
FROM    Projects a
        LEFT JOIN Scores b
            ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID
GROUP   BY a.ProjectID, a.ProjectName
HAVING  COUNT(a.ProjectID) < 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06b480/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ PROJECTID ║ PROJECTNAME ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║        11 ║ Volcano     ║
║        15 ║ Robots      ║
║        22 ║ Oceanlife   ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks so much JW!  It's that blasted HAVING clause that I just can't seem to master.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
SELECT  a.ProjectID, a.ProjectName
FROM    Projects a
LEFT JOIN (select ProjectID, count(*) counted from Scores) b
       ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID
WHERE COALESCE(b.counted,0) < 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(scores.id) AS score_count, projects.* 
FROM scores, projects
WHERE scores.projectid = projects.id
GROUP BY projects.id
HAVING score_count > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from scores where id not in (select id from scores where project id in (select projectid from scores group by projectid having count(prjectid)=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Projects p WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Scores s WHERE s.projectid = p.projectid) < 3
```